# NullPointerException when validtion object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I get **NullPointerException** when validating object. I send to controller dto, and when validating it. I cant understan where is the problem because product that goes into validate method is not null, Validator code :

```
@Override
public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {

    Product product = (Product) o;

    if (product.getTitle().isEmpty() || product.getTitle() == null) {
        errors.rejectValue("title", "product.title", "Product title cant be empty");
    }
    if (product.getDescription().isEmpty() || product.getDescription() == null) {
        errors.rejectValue("description", "product.description", "Product description cant be empty");
    }
    if (product.getPrice().isNaN() || product.getPrice()<=0 || product.getPrice() == null) {
        errors.rejectValue("price", "product.price", "Product price is not valid");
    }
    if (product.getCategory()==null) {
        errors.rejectValue("category", "product.category", "Product category is not valid");
    }

}
```

and i get this

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.shop.validator.ProductValidator.validate(ProductValidator.java:27)
>     com.shop.controller.ProductController.createProduct(ProductController.java:82)
>     com.shop.controller.ProductController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c0d382c4.invoke()
>     org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)

Comment: Since the Java code you've posted is obviously not complete source files, could you let us know where line 27 of `ProductValidator` and line 82 of `ProductController` are?

Comment: if (product.getPrice().isNaN() || product.getPrice()<=0 || product.getPrice() == null) {
            errors.rejectValue("price", "product.price", "Product price is not valid");
        } it is 27th  and 82th is  productValidator.validate(product,bindingResult);

Comment: Reopened because I don't believe this is a duplicate of "What is a NullPointerException", which is too generic.  This question has to do with how short-circuit operators work, and the proposed duplicate doesn't address that.

Answer (score 2):

`||` evaluates from left to right.  So if you say

```
x == null || x.somethingSomething()
```

and if `x` is null, the first condition will catch the case, and it will prevent the method call on a `null` reference from happening.  But if you say

```
x.somethingSomething() || x == null
```

and if `x` is null, it tries to evaluate the method call first, and throws an exception before it gets to the `null` check.  Java (or any other computer language I'm aware of) isn't smart enough to "figure out" to do the null check first.  It trusts the order you give it.

Similarly with `&&`:

```
if (x != null && x.something())
```

will do the null check at the right time, but

```
if (x.something() && x != null)
```

won't.